# How to create a navigation bar on the left and container on the right?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make a template like this:

[image]

This is HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="label">label A</div>
  <div class="text">text A text A text A</div>

  <div class="label">label B</div>
  <div class="text">text B text B text B</div>

  <div class="label">label C</div>
  <div class="text">text C text C text C</div>
</div>
```

I want to display all label tags as navigation on the left, and the content is on the right

Note: Can not wrap labels, just use that sample code.

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: How to make that code like the attach image ?

Comment: Just looking towards the image is not giving a full idea of what you actually want to achieve, it would be great if you can share what you have tried and where you have been struck.

Comment: @CodeReady here my code https://jsfiddle.net/6dyj3zar/1/ , I just do sample code, I want when hover **label**, the next text will show in right not below

Comment: if you just want to show text on lable hover, then take a look at here I have created a raw fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/rtmybqcj/ but as mentioned by @Tan would be a better approach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called *sidebar*. You can search on Google for it. There are a lot of template about sidebar.

In this example, I've just used `display` css property with `inline-block` value for previewing.

```css
.sidebar, .content {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 12px;
}

.sidebar {
  margin-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebar">
  <div class="label">label A</div>
  
  <div class="label">label B</div>
  
  <div class="label">label C</div>
</div>
<div class="content">
  <div class="text">text A text A text A</div>
  
  <div class="text">text B text B text B</div>
  
  <div class="text">text C text C text C</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am kind of confused as to what you mean by "cannot wrap labels". Are you saying that you can't edit the HTML at all? The way you have it setup will make it challenging to get the desired effect you want.

What I would do is have 2 wrappers on the same hierarchy, one contains the menu for your labels and the other contains your sub menu.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="label">label A</div>
  <div class="label">label B</div>
  <div class="label">label C</div>
</div>
<div class="wrapper-2">
  <div class="text">text A text A text A</div>
  <div class="text">text B text B text B</div>
  <div class="text">text C text C text C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, Do you have other idea with my code if do not edit HTML ?